# prevent figures from appearing in first column

Tags: floats, two-column

Ideally, I would put a figure in the `tex` file with the paragraph it belongs to. This way, LaTeX does most of the work of positioning the figure for me.

Often I do not want any figures to appear in the first column or even the first page however. As a quick fix I have been moving the figure in the source file to get it to appear in the second column. I am however wondering: is there a way to make LaTeX postpone shipping the figure  until the second column?

Edit (in response to the comment below):
I'm using the `IEEEtran` documentclass (journal supplied). The figures are usually a column wide (ca 10cm). I don't want figures to appear in the very first column because the journal does not like that (but oddly enough did not modify the documentclass to not place figures there).

Edit2:
This is a MWE of my problem

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
A first paragraph. \lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
    This is in the figure
\end{figure}

The second paragraph. \lipsum[1]

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Resulting in (top of the first page only):

[image: Resulting output]

The figure is clearly placed in the first column, although there is a title specified.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you use. Please also provide at least something akin to a hint regarding how large your floats tend to be. If you absolutely don't want them to "float" (in the LaTeX sense of the word), you should probably not be using `figure` and `table` environments to begin with. Incidentally, would you mind telling us what's undesirable about having a float in the first (i.e., left-hand) column of a two-column document (other than, of course, on the very first page)? Having this information might help coming up with a better coding strategy.

Comment: If you use `\usepackage{flafter}` then `t` floats can not appear in the first column unless they are the first thing in the file.

Comment: @Mico: see the edits to the question

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: if I understand correctly, this will change the figure placement of subsequent columns and pages as well. Since I like that placement and there is usually only one figure at the start of the paper, I prefer the solution of manually moving the figure in the first column over such an intrusive option.

Comment: You have provided no example so it is hard to help, but IEEEtran uses same code as `article` to suppress top floats on the first page, I'll post some code in a (non) answer.

Comment: I've added a MWE. If I understand you correctly, the documentclass should already prevent the figure from appearing in the first column, but that is not what I'm seeing. Am I misinterpreting your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most classes, including `article` and `IEEEtran` suppress top floats in the implementation fo `\maketitle` so as long as you have a title at the start of the article there should be no top float in the first column.

`article.cls has

```
\newcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%
    \long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 1em\noindent
            \hb@xt@1.8em{%
                \hss\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}##1}%
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
```

and `IEEEtran` has a similar setting of `\@topnum` with nost of its options

```
% user command to invoke the title page
\def\maketitle{\par%
  \begingroup%
  \normalfont%
  \def\thefootnote{}%  the \thanks{} mark type is empty
  \def\footnotemark{}% and kill space from \thanks within author
  \let\@makefnmark\relax% V1.7, must *really* kill footnotemark to remove all \textsuperscript spacing as well.
  \footnotesize%       equal spacing between thanks lines
  \footnotesep 0.7\baselineskip%see global setting of \footnotesep for more info
  % V1.7 disable \thanks note indention for compsoc
  \@IEEEcompsoconly{\long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 1em\noindent\hbox{\@makefnmark}##1}}%
  \normalsize%
  \ifCLASSOPTIONpeerreview
     \newpage\global\@topnum\z@ \@maketitle\@IEEEstatictitlevskip\@IEEEaftertitletext%
     \thispagestyle{IEEEpeerreviewcoverpagestyle}\@thanks%
  \else
     \if@twocolumn%
        \ifCLASSOPTIONtechnote%
           \newpage\global\@topnum\z@ \@maketitle\@IEEEstatictitlevskip\@IEEEaftertitletext%
        \else
           \twocolumn[{\IEEEquantizevspace{\@maketitle}[\IEEEquantizedisabletitlecmds]{0pt}[-\topskip]{\baselineskip}{\@IEEENORMtitlevspace}{\@IEEEMINtitlevspace}\@IEEEaftertitletext}]%
        \fi
     \else
        \newpage\global\@topnum\z@ \@maketitle\@IEEEstatictitlevskip\@IEEEaftertitletext%
     \fi
     \thispagestyle{IEEEtitlepagestyle}\@thanks%
  \fi
```

so as for `article` the title should be set in a column with `\@topnum` set to zero, or in a two-column span inside `\twocolumn[...]` so in either case there should be no float above the title.